# rails generate rspec:install - no such file to load  -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#top), and when I try to use the RSpec generator

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/rcooke/sample_app/config/application.rb:13
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Following the other discussions on this same problem, I have changed my Gemfile to contain the following:

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

I added both rspec and rspec-rails to the Gemfile after noticing they are both installed:

```
Using rspec-core (2.9.0)
Using rspec-expectations (2.9.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
Using rspec (2.9.0)
Using rspec-rails (2.9.0)
```

I've even carried out:

```
$ gem install rspec
```

Maybe i'm not using the correct procedure to update. Once I've saved the Gemfile on my computer i'm using **bundle update** and **bundle install**. Trying **rails generate rspec:install** still fails.

Update: when I try to run the resource i get the following error:

```
$ rake spec
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
```

Update: I've obviously screwed something up. Now if I attempt to start a new application I get the following error.

```
$ rails new sample_app2 --skip-test-unit
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find json (~> 1.4) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.2, actionpack-3.2.2, activemodel-3.2.2, activerecord-3.2.2, activeresource-3.2.2, activesupport-3.2.2, addressable-2.2.7, arel-3.0.2, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.1.3, bundler-1.1.2, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.2.0, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.3.0, heroku-2.22.0, heroku-2.21.3, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, journey-1.0.3, jquery-rails-2.0.1, json_pure-1.6.6, launchy-2.1.0, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.18, multi_json-1.2.0, multi_json-1.1.0, netrc-0.7.1, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.2, railties-3.2.2, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, rest-client-1.6.7, rspec-2.9.0, rspec-core-2.9.0, rspec-expectations-2.9.0, rspec-mocks-2.9.0, rspec-rails-2.9.0, rubyzip-0.9.6.1, sass-3.1.15, sass-rails-3.2.5, sprockets-2.3.1, sprockets-2.1.2, sqlite3-1.3.5, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.32, uglifier-1.2.3] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:772:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the SQlite3 library installed on your system? When you look in */usr/lib/* for libsqlite3.so (assuming you're on Linux) do you see it? if not then could you try installing it (via apt-get/portage/your package manager) and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm using Cygwin on Windows. I searched in the lib directory, and although i have plenty of libsqlite3 files, I don't have one with the .so extension.